# How to export a Spring Boot project to an executable standalone file?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have created a project in Spring Tool Suite with Spring Boot and Gradle, and I really don't know how to export to make it work.

I don't know much about gradle, just the basics to add dependencies from the maven repository. So in some articles says to apply the application plugin to do the task, but I don't know how to set up the configuration file and how to create the executable.

If anyone could write or link a step by step detailed explanation on how to do it, it would be very much appreciated.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.rodamientosbulnes.objetivosventa.Application"
    executable = true
}

jar {
    baseName = 'objetivosventa'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc')
    compile('net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.13')
    compile('com.miglayout:miglayout-swing:4.2')
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build file looks fine, you only need to run `gradle build` (or `Run As -> Gradle -> Gradle build` in the STS) to create the runnable jar.

More details about configuration of the gradle plugin are available on [spring boot documentation site](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html).

Comment: Thank you!!, what a idiot I was, I didn't know that it creates with just the build task.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle's application plugin doesn't make a single execitable for you, but it can create a distribution, which includes all the dependencies, jar-artifact for your project and 2 scripts to run it (one batch-file and linex executable).

The main thing you need to know, is that `spring-boot` plugin already provide all the task from `application` plugin you may need. All the task you can find [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). You need `distZip` or `installDist` to package your project to the distribution. This task will create a ready project distribution under your `project-folder/build` folder. One more task you may find usefull is `buildRun` which will run you spring-boot application without package it into distribution.